# Determining the size of the smallest resolvable detail for a given camera

Tags: lens, focal-length, sensor, optics, resolution

**My generic question:**

Given camera specifications, e.g:

- sensor resolution,
- sensor image area,
- pixel size (area),
- optical size,
- focal length (ratio),
- fov (horizontal and/or vertical)

and distance to an object to be view, how can i determine the smallest resolvable detail by this camera?

**Context:**

I am trying to build a detector for detecting defects in my products (plastic beads of about 3 mm). These defect have a range of sizes, on average they are about 100 micron but we would like to be able to detect 50 micron and up. These plastic beads will be falling down through a pipe and i will have the camera capture an image as it passes and use a processing step (based on color difference mostly) to find any defects on the bead. I want defects of size 50 micron and up to be resolved quite well, i.e. 50 micron defects have several tens to hundreds of pixels.

Comment: it sounds more like a question for https://physics.stackexchange.com or https://engineering.stackexchange.com
I feel like this problem was solved before, maybe you need something not image-based, but single-detector based. For example, you can try have a laser beam go through the tube with beads, its deflection or attenuation, or change in profile will signal defect. And it is much faster to analzye and cheaper to build, probably

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about building a detector, not the production of photographs, and the technical answers you want aren't the same as answers that would be useful for the art and science of photography.

Comment: @mattdm if the technical answers that the OP wants aren't part of the science of photography, what is?

Comment: @BrandonDube The science of photography is the science of making images with light. This is about computer vision. The things that are important here aren't the same as the things that are important for making a photograph for the sake of the photograph.

Comment: We disagree on the definition of the science of photography.

Comment: @aaa I am not asking about building the detector, it is just the context for asking my question. My question: "What is the smallest resolvable detail given camera specifications" is equally applicable to landscapes, still-lifes, whatever you want.

Comment: @mattdm Any part of science is not only understanding the subject you are studying/observing but also understanding the tools you are using to do said observing. I want to know more about the limitations of a certain specifica camera setup which i use to observe my subject. It is irrelevant what my specific subject is, other than that i provide it as a clarification for asking my question.

Comment: @nluigi this is one of the "XY problem". You are asking not to how solve your real problem (detect defects) but how to implement your proposed solution. At least it is less effective. This might clear things https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question, and is something serious photographers should be very interested in. Yes, the answer comes from physics, but that is true for virtually every other question at some level. Part of the *craft* of photography is having a deep technical understanding of how your tools work. This ridiculous pedantry about what constitutes photography would mean that half of the content in Ansel Adams' books would be off-topic here, which I think it's a harmful attitude and totally bewildering to me.

Comment: Yes, you can take good photographs without technical understanding, and indeed many good photographs were taken this way, but that doesn't mean we should not strive for technical understanding, or that technical understanding doesn't have a positive effect on the photographs you take.

Comment: For example, the answer to this question directly and unequivocally influences the way one does astrophotography, which is 100% on-topic here.

Comment: I'm not opposed to questions about the science of how optical systems work. I just think that in this particular case, the answer has little applicability beyond the specific computer-vision use case.

Comment: But it's fine if y'all disagree. That's why there's a voting system. :)

Comment: Also, if there's general consensus that we want to open the site to more computer-vision or other camera-system focused questions, we can do that — please start a discussion on [meta]. I'm not just arbitrarily against this kind of question — I think they're detrimental to the site for actual reasons. And I think as suggested in the first comment that one of the other network sites is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @mattdm - Searching for "plastic pellet sorter" turns up ready made equipment for ~10-50K. Not sure he's going to DIY (Camera, Software, Mechanical) for less: https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/plastic-pellet-color-sorter.html - It's an interesting question about resolution but ultimately it's a question about machinery (or starting a one man business to compete with existing equipment).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want tens to hundreds of pixels per 50 micron area, you need a microscope.  Based on your object size, with that resolution, you want at least  10px/50um * 3000um/50um a 600px wide view of your bead, and up to a 6000px wide view of your bead.

Common sensor sizes are 24x36mm, 16x24mm, and smaller in industrial cameras.

You're going to need, roughly, 3-5x magnification for the bigger sensor sizes (36mm and 24mm), and lower for smaller sensor sizes (closer to 1x).

Shop for microscope objectives with this sort of field of view.  They will mostly all be diffraction limited, ish, at pretty big apertures (f/2 and faster).  You can use 2.44*wavelength * fno to get the spot size.  In vis, that's about 2.44*.55*2 = 2.684 microns.

A 16mm wide sensor with 2.64 micron pixels is 5500px wide.

So you have not violated any resolution limits, but you are operating close to them for your 100px/50um target.

I do not expect you will find a system that can get images out of a camera at this speed, and processed, in anything resembling real time.  Your best possible speed is probably 1-3fps.

The working distance of microscopes is usually/always short.  If that is not suitable for your needs, you need a custom system (be prepared to spend upwards of $100,000/system) that would be near the limits of what is possible re: element sizes and resolution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am wondering how you determined which magnification was needed from the required field of fiew and the image sensor size? Don't you need a working distance for this?

Comment: Your object is 3mm wide, and you want it to fit on the sensor.  So the image can be at most [short dimension] long, usually a bit less to allow some positioning error.  16/3 ~= 5, I rounded that to 3-5x.  Significantly underfilling the sensor will requiring processing lots of "waste" pixels and also increase the resolution requirements of the system.